# Selenium driver executable does not exist in file path

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I use the latest version of R 3.4.1

I installed RSelenium through Tools -> Install Packages

It was installed successfully.

When I tried to run rs driver I take this error:

> rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)

```
Selenium message:The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\username\Documents

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

How is it possible to receive this error for this file path when I can see that R Selenium installed in this file path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpuYCpfE\downloaded_packages`
and I can find RSelenium in this path `C:\Users\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\RSelenium`

What can I do in order not to receive this error?

I tried previous versions of r, I tried to unistall and install again rstudio and r also I tried this when I load the RSelenium `library("RSelenium",lib.loc = "C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")`

Comment: when i had this problem last month (on Ubuntu 16.04), the following command installed the jar file : `checkForServer()`.  See if that solves the issue. Edit- It's an R command

Comment: Have you added this path in Windows Environment variable `PATH`

Comment: @R.S. checkForServer() is an old version in order to use r selenium I found the script of checkForServer function in path I copy/pasted the function in r command and after that I pressed checkForServer() but it has an error. How   could you run the checkForServer()?

Comment: @SunilT yes I added but again the problem is still the same

Comment: @Dimisc First off, I'm copying frim the documentation for CehckforServer. This should help you get the binary and drop it in its right directory. It's a jar file :  `The downloads for the Selenium project can be found at http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. This convience function downloads the standalone server and places it in the RSelenium package directory bin folder by default.` My RSelenium version is  `1.6.2`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I use the jar file given here. http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.4/

Comment: @R.S. thank you. The version of RSelenium I use is 1.7.1. I put the jar file in the file path of checkforserver I tried to run it but I receive this error `Error in xmlParse(paste0(selURL), "/?delimiter=") : 
  could not find function "xmlParse"`

Comment: @Dimisc funny. that function is a part of `XML` package. You can try to load the package separately with `require` if RSelenium did not do that